# PopUp binding not done correctly

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, popup

I have a listview which on mouse enter to a particular column, i try to launch a popup in viewmodel class by setting isOpen to true in MyAction2() function which gets called on when user enters mouse on that column of listview.

I observe that when the mouse-enter to that column.It calls my function (MyAction2() function in ViewModel, see code written below) but even on setting the isopen variable to true in MyAction2(), The set-get method of binded isOpen not get called. Now i feel there is problem in binding. Which normally should be correct i feel some thing is missing but i dont know what.

My Xaml (containing teh opup and the column in ListView which on mouse enter calls an event called MyAction2() in ViewModel):

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>           
        <Popup Margin="10,10,0,13" Name="Popup1" IsOpen="{Binding PopUpLaunched,Mode=TwoWay}" Placement="Top" PopupAnimation="Fade" StaysOpen="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="194" Height="200" MinWidth="500" MinHeight="500">
            <StackPanel>
                <Border Background="Red">
                    <TextBlock Name="McTextBlock" Background="LightBlue"> This is popup text </TextBlock>
                </Border>
            </StackPanel>
        </Popup>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

ViewModel.cs

```
private bool popUpLaunched;
public bool PopUpLaunched {
    get {
        return popUpLaunched;
    } //Get set never gets called even after the popUpLaunched=true in the MyAction2() call
    set {
        popUpLaunched = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("PopUpLaunched");
    }
}

private void MyAction2(object param) //The function which gets called on mouse event but do not pop ups the popup
    {
        popUpLaunched = true;
    }
```

Whats wrong and where is wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the **P**opupLaunched *property* instead of setting the popUpLaunched field for the setter to get called and the PropertyChanged event to get raised:

```
private void MyAction2(object param)
{
    PopUpLaunched = true;
}
```

Comment: Ohh god.. 3 hours wasted for it :'(

Comment: But normally we assign values to private variable, AM i right ?

Comment: No, you should always set the *property* for the PropertyChanged event to get raised whenever you want something to happen in the view. The views listens to property changes, it doesn't know anything about fields.

Comment: Ok, Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

In order to implement such a binding, you can make that property a Dependency property like this

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty PopUpLaunched = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "popUpLaunched", typeof(bool), typeof(MainPage), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public bool popUpLaunched
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(PopUpLaunched); }
            set { SetValue(PopUpLaunched, value); }
        }
```

If you are not working on the MainPage, change that typeof(MainPage) argument respectively. And adjust getter and setter for your needs.